# Sun or the Sun?

Tags: articles, capitalization, definite-articles

I'm coming up with a tagline for a solar company logo that says 'All you need is the Sun'. I am however confused with the use of 'the' and the capitalisation of 'sun' here. Are they necessary or 'All you need is sun' sufficient enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capitalization or otherwise of 'sun' is a useful (but optional) device for distinguishing between our sun (i.e. the one at the centre of our own solar system) and suns somewhere else.

'The Sun' thus refers specifically to our sun, whereas 'sun' can mean both *a sun* (e.g. "That solar system has two suns"), *our sun* (e.g. "Remember not to look directly at the sun!") and *sunlight* (e.g. "It's time you came in out of the sun"), and is therefore ambiguous.

So how you decide to answer the question you have asked will depend on what you are trying to convey.

If you mean "All you need is (our) sun", then the most appropriate wording is "All you need is the Sun" or "All you need is the sun".

If you mean "All you need is sunlight", then I'd suggest you use that form of words if you want to avoid the ambiguity of "All you need is sun".

Comment: It seems to be a general slogan for companies of such kind, however, the capitalization probably  is for formatting purpose. Find two more instances of such expression in the following links. http://www.maccoenergy.com/solar-energy/   and
http://homeofsolarenergy.com/

Comment: Although technically speaking, solar power comes from "sunlight", it would sound warmer if you said "sunshine". Of course, there is "sunlight" even on a cloudy day, but "sunshine" only on a sunny day (or portion ), so pick whichever seems apt.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds better the Sun because it somehow implies that is referring to sunlight, almost everything that is "all you need" can be changed to "you only need".

Comment: Actually, it is _sun_ that would imply "sunlight", whereas _the Sun_ implies the star. As for changing _all you need_ to anything, it is a very, _very_ commonly used phrase (see for instance [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKiqthx0GKw) ) and probably more idiomatic than "you only need".

Comment: @oerkelens well I was answering the question with the idea that it was for a company logo, a regular consumers always welcomes a character which in this case is "the Sun". I said "almost" anything, answering with a consumerism approach,  "all you need" implies everything and most of the cases everything implies plural objects, as of "you only" implies a single thing. what do you need? all or everything, vs only or just one. I used the consumerism approach. I agree with you.

Comment: @Meed or Got sunlight? or Got sun?  lol

Comment: "You only" implies a single thing? How so? I only want an explanation and a reference ... ^^